Reference request: De Moivre - Laplace Integral Theorem
I have learnt the Local Limit Theorem reading Shiryaev's Probability-1 graduate textbook. However, I find his proof of the Integral Theorem rather challenging and confusing. Even though I get the meaning of the theorem, I struggle to understand its proof. Therefore, I am looking for a different source - perhaps a book or a paper accessible to undergraduate students - to learn the proof of this theorem.
EDIT: I am looking for the following theorem:

Let $$ 0<p<1, P_n(k):= \binom n k p^kq^{n-k}, P_n(a, b] := \sum_{a<x\leq b} P_n(np+x\sqrt{npq}), $$ where $q = 1-p$ and the summation is taken over those $x$ for which $np+x\sqrt{npq}$ is an integer.
Then $$\sup_{-\infty\leq a< b \leq \infty} \left|P_n(a, b] - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_a^b e^{-x^2/2} dx\right| \to 0$$ as $n\to \infty$.

To be honest, I don't even get what $$\sup_{-\infty\leq a< b \leq \infty}$$ means here: shouldn't $a, b$ be fixed?

The result you are looking for is?

@Andrew thanks for pointing that out. I have just added the statement of the theorem I am looking for. I thought the name "De Moivre-Laplace integral theorem" was used by everyone

Convergence in distribution means that $F_n(x) \to F(x)$ for every continuity point $x$ of $F$ as $n\to\infty$. If $F$ is continuous, then $F_n(x)\to F(x)$ for every $x$ implies that $\sup_{x\in \mathbb R}|F_n(x)-F(x)| \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. It is a nice exercise to show this (not entirely trivial, but also not so difficult). A simpler proof does work here though because of the symmetry of the standard gaussian measure.

@Andrew could you please be more specific? I have no idea what to do with your hints

Suppose you show that $P_n(-\infty,x] \to \mu((-\infty,x])$ for every $x$ where $\mu$ is the standard gaussian measure. Can you show uniform convergence from this?

@Andrew I'm not sure I understood your previous comment properly: are you claiming that pointwise convergence of a sequence of distribution functions to a continuous distribution function is actually uniform? As for your last comment, I feel like I can conclude observing that $P_n(a, b] = P_n(-\infty, b] - P_n(-\infty, a]$ but I'm still rather confused

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
